# Login system data validating from database

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
$pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');


$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'webexam');

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
else{


$sql="SELECT username FROM account WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";

if($user==$sql){
    echo"LOGIN success";

}else{
    echo"Check yo password";
}    
}
```

?>
I am planning to do login and registering system. Registering side is complete but seems like there is a problem in login side. Currently I am trying to compare the username that inserted and username that is in DB. But it is no go, please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never store plain text passwords. Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection. Have you tried to print out the sql statement and took a look if it is what you expect?

Comment: You're not actually executing the query. And you should be using a prepared statement to protect yourself from SQL injection. And you should not be storing passwords in plain text, use `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead.

Comment: Hello Meld. It is very good you are trying to learn. Unfortunately, tutorials you are using are severely outdated and outright dangerous. Please see [how to connect](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) and [how to select](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select) properly

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score -1):

Use query like

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM account WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

after that check result array with help of print_r LIke

```
print_r($result);
```

After that compare user condition

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)